# Checkbox not getting checked in datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am dynamically set `CheckBox` column of few rows in a `DataGridView` as "checked on".

I have tried a lot of things. Following is the sample code. :

```
DataGridViewCheckBoxCell chk = (DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)dataGridRow.Cells["colChk"];
chk.Selected = true;
chk.Value = 1;
```

Comment: Code doesn't compile since the Cells array belongs to a Row object.  Using just CurrentRow, your code works.  Need more code to understand the issue.

Comment: Yes, Grant Winney you are correct. Any suggesstions to resolve this issue would be appreciated.

Comment: But the code works, so it's unclear why it doesn't work for you.  Hence, we need to see more code.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested my case, it works fine.

```
private void AddRow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
}

private void ChangeCheck_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.SelectedRows)
    {
        if (row.Cells[0].ValueType == typeof(bool))
        {
            if (row.Cells[0].Value == null)
                row.Cells[0].Value = true;
            else
                row.Cells[0].Value = !(bool)row.Cells[0].Value;
        }
    }
}
```

If DataGridView bind the DataSouce I suggest you can only change your property from true->false and if you need more help, please comment my post.